# I have a perl script that is passing a parameter in from an html file and then prints that parameter to the file

Tags: perl

So I have written a perl scrip to pass a parameter from an HTML file and then take that vaule of the parameter and write it to a file, then read the file and complie the data. here is the body of the html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title> poll.html </title>
<meta charset = "utf-8" />
<style type = "text/css">     
</style>
</head>
<!-- the quiz -->
<body>
<form action = "../cgi-bin/poll.pl" method = "post">
</h1> this is a poll<br><br>What is your favorite color?</h1>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red">Red<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="green">Green<br>
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">Blue<br>
        <input type = "submit"  value = "Submit Quiz" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

then I have my perl script which all works but once I open my file I lose the value of $color I tried making $color a global varable but the same error occurred (Use of uninitialized value $color in concatenation (.) or string at poll.pl line 19.) here is the perl script:
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

```
# processOrder.pl
use CGI ":standard";
use strict;
use warnings;
print header;
print start_html("Pizza Places Order Form");
#Set local variables to the parameter values 
our($color)=param("color");
my $filename = 'data.txt';
open(my $fh, '+>>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh "'$color'\n";
my $red = 0;
my $blue = 0;
my $green = 0;
while( my $line = <$fh>)  {   
    if (index($line, "red\n") != -1) {
    $blue = $blue + 1;} 
if (index($line, "blue\n") != -1) {
    $blue = $blue + 1;}
if (index($line, "gren\n") != -1) {
    $green = $green + 1;}
}
my $total = $red + $green +$blue;
if ($total == 0){
$total = 1}
print  h4("percent blue = ", $blue/$total, "\n");
print  h4("percent green = ", $green/$total,  "\n");
print  h4("percent red = ", $red/$total, "\n");
close $fh;
```

final warning im new to perl but I do think that this logic is sound any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you "lose the value of $color"?

Comment: when the script is compiled using /usr/bin/perl it runs into an error that says I cannot print the $color value to this file because it hasn't been initialized. I initialized it but the complier thinks that it hasn't been and I cant seem to find a way to trick it into thinking it has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your script. Here are the three main ones:

1. You append text to the end a file, then you try to read the contents of the file. The problem is that your read cursor is at the end of your file and so you read nothing. You need to reset the read cursor to the start of the file before you try to read it. Use `seek $fh, 0, 0;`
2. You append `'blue'` to the file, but you compare it against `blue` (you're missing the single quotes). You'll never get any matches.
3. You test if the line matches `red\n` and if it does... you increment `$blue`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit older thread, but one thing I did notice too is that you're not using chomp. When you read from stdin (or from a form or whatever) and want to compare it to a string, it's a good idea to chomp($var) first to get rid of the newline. If there is no newline, then the function does nothing (unlike chop() which will remove the last character regardless of what it is.)

So this:

```
if (index($line, "red\n") != -1) {
```

Would become this:

```
if (index(chomp($line), "red") != -1) {
```

It's not a huge deal, but in cases where you're not sure if a newline follows, it's a good practice. This is especially true if the string you are reading is at the end of the file and no newline is present, which is relatively common at least in *nix environments.